# Yang-Lee circle theorem and the distribution of zeros

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, partition-function

I am reading a [note](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0510278) on Yang-Lee's zeros.

The note first focuses on the grand canonical partition function $\Xi(T, z)$, where $z$ is the complex fugacity conjugate to the number of particles. If the zeros form a curve closing in/reaching onto a special **real** value $z_0$, it is shown that the curve is a **hyperbola** when $z_0$ corresponds to a first order phase transition, and it forms two **straight lines** when $z_0$ correspond to a second order transition.

The Circle theorem concerns about the partition function $Z$, which involves the statement that roots of $Z$ are confined on **circles**.

I wonder how the two statements on the **shape** of the zero locus are related?